# Construct a Matlab array through nested loops

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have three matrices `A_1`, `A_2`, `A_3` each of dimension `mxn`, where `m` and `n` are large. These matrices contain strictly positive numbers.

I want to construct a matrix `check` of dimension `mx1` such that, for each `i=1,...,m`:

`check(i)=1` if **there exists** `j,k` such that

`A_1(i,1)+A_2(j,1)+A_3(k,1)<=quantile(A_1(i,2:end)+A_2(j,2:end)+A_3(k,3:end), 0.95)`

In my case `m` is large (`m=10^5`) and `n=500`. Therefore, I would like your help to find an efficient way to do this.

---

Below I reproduce an example. I impose `m` smaller than in reality and report my incomplete and probably inefficient attempt to construct `check`.

```
clear
rng default
m=4;
n=500;
A_1=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
A_2=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
A_3=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
check=zeros(m,1);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:m
        for k=1:m
            if A_1(i,1)+A_2(j,1)+A_3(k,1)<=quantile(A_1(i,2:end)+A_2(j,2:end)+A_3(k,2:end), 0.95)
              check(i)=1;
              STOP TO LOOP OVER j AND k, MOVE TO THE NEXT i (INCOMPLETE!)              
           else
            KEEP SEARCHING FOR j,k SUCH THAT THE CONDITION IS SATISFIED (INCOMPLETE!) 
           end
       end
    end
end
```

Comment: What are `A_2` and `A_3` for? I don't see them being used in calculating `check`. Or did you mean `A_2(j, ...)` and `A_3(k, ...)`?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, it was a typo

Comment: And is `check` of size `mxn` or `mx1`? You said it's `mxn` but defined it as `mx1`.

Comment: Thanks. Definitively mx1.

Comment: You can't cut the number of times you compute the quantile, which is the most expensive operation here. You won't be able to vectorize this either. The only optimization I can come up with so far is to move the indexing outside the loops: `A_1_1 = A_1(:,1)` and `A_1 = A_1(:,2:end)`. That should speed up your code a little bit, I think. Or maybe not, but worth a try.

Comment: You could also try playing with a third dimension. Adding a `mxn` array to a `1xnxm` array adds the `mxn` array to each `mxn` slice of the 3D array.

Comment: Like so: `x = reshape(1:20, 5, 4); y = reshape(100:100:2000, 1, 4, 5); z = x + y;`. Then use `any` to check the condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a scalar `x` and a vector `v` the expression `x <=quantile (v, .95)` can be written as `sum( x > v) < Q` where `Q = .95 * numel(v)` *.

Also `A_1` can be splitted before the loop to avoid extra indexing.
Moreover the most inner loop can be removed in favor of vectorization.

```
Af_1 = A_1(:,1);
Af_2 = A_2(:,1);
Af_3 = A_3(:,1);
As_1 = A_1(:,2:end);
As_2 = A_2(:,2:end);
As_3 = A_3(:,2:end);
Q = .95 * (n -1);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:m
        if any (sum (Af_1(i) + Af_2(j) + Af_3 > As_1(i,:) + As_2(j,:) + As_3, 2) < Q)
            check(i) = 1;
            break; 
        end             
    end
end
```

More optimization can be achieved by rearranging the expressions involved in the inequality and pre-computation:

```
lhs = A_3(:,1) - A_3(:,2:end);
lhsi = A_1(:,1) - A_1(:,2:end);
rhsj = A_2(:,2:end) - A_2(:,1);
Q = .95 * (n - 1);
for i=1:m
    LHS = lhs + lhsi(i,:);
    for j=1:m
        if any (sum (LHS > rhsj(j,:), 2) < Q)
            check(i) = 1;
            break; 
        end             
    end
end
```

- Note that because of the method that is used in the computation of [quantile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html) you may get a slightly different result.

Comment: Nice! Removing the call to `quantile` must be a huge time saver!

Comment: Thanks. It still takes too much. Each iteration of `j` takes `0.002 sec`. Hence, each iteration of `i` takes `0.002*m=200 sec`. Thus, overall it takes `0.002*m^2=20000000 sec`.

Comment: Note that because of `break` the computation related to the remaining `j` s may be discarded and overall time is probably less than your (worst case) estimate.

Comment: @user3285148 I have corrected the mistake in the answer. The expression `sum( x <= v) >= Q` is changed to to `sum( x > v) < Q` and the code is updated.

Comment: @user3285148: Do you have any indication that it is possible to compute this faster? You are computing something for 10^15 possible combinations, even if each combination were to take only one clock cycle, you're still looking at 2 GHz = 10^15 / 2.10^9 = 500000 s = 5.8 days. And the likelihood of computing a quantile over 500 values every clock cycle...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Because all numbers are positive, you can do some optimizations. 95 percentile will be only higher if you add `A1` to the mix - if you find the `j` and `k` of greatest 95 percentile of `A2+A3` on the right side compared to the sum of the first 2 elements, you can simply take that for every `i`.

```
maxDif = -inf;
for j = 1 : m
   for k = 1 : m
      newDif = quantile(A_2..., 0.95) - A_2(j,1)-A_3(k,1);
      maxDif = max(newDif, maxDif);
   end
end
```

If even that is too slow, you can first get `maxDifA2` and `maxDifA3`, then estimate that `maxDif` will be for those particular `j` and `k` values and calculate it.

Now, for some numbers you will get that `maxDif > A_1`, then the `check` is 1. For some numbers you will get that `maxDif + quantile(A1, 0.95) < A_1`, here `check` is 0 (if you estimated `maxDif` by separate calculation of A2 and A3 this isn't true!). For some (most?) you will unfortunately get values in between and this won't be helpful at all. Then what remains is option 2 (it is also more straightforward):

Option 2:
You could save some time if you can save summation `A_2+A_3` on the right side, as that calculation repeats for every different `i`, but that requires A LOT of memory. But `quantile` is the more expensive operation anyway, so you aren't saving a lot of time. Something along the lines of

```
for j = 1 : m
for k = 1 : m
A23R(j,k,:) = A2(j,:)+A3(k,:); % Unlikely to fit in memory.
end
end
```

Then you can perform your loops, using A23R and avoiding to repeat that sum for every `i`.