# Summing across all possible rows of 4 Matlab arrays

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have four Matlab arrays `A_1`, `A_2`, `A_3`, `A_4` each of dimension `mxn`, where `m` is potentially large. These matrices contain strictly positive numbers.

```
clear
rng default
m=4;
n=500;
A_1=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
A_2=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
A_3=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
A_4=betarnd(1,2,m,n);
```

---

**What I want to do in words:**

I want to construct a matrix `B` of dimension `bx4` such that each row of `B` reports
indices  `[i,j,k,h]` if

`A_1(i,1)+A_2(j,1)+A_3(k,1)+A_4(h,1)<=quantile(A_1(i,2:end)+A_2(j,2:end)+A_3(k,2:end),A_4(h,2:end) 0.95)`

for each of `i,j,k,h` going from `1` to `m`.

Note that `b` can be at most `m^4`.

---

What I want to do can be implemented by looping over `i,j,k,h`. However, I need to handle a large `m`. Hence, I would like your help to build a very efficient code which, in turn, can help me to understand how far I can push `m`.

---

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851294/construct-a-matlab-array-through-nested-loops)  is extremely helpful, even though addresses a slightly different question. Below, I'm trying to readapt it for my specific case. Can it be improved? Also, I don't know how to properly store the indices in `B`.

```
lhs4=A_4(:,1)-A_4(:,2:end); %mx(n-1)
lhs1=A_1(:,1)-A_1(:,2:end);
lhs2=A_2(:,1)-A_2(:,2:end);
rhs3=A_3(:,2:end)-A_3(:,1);
Q = .95 * (n - 1);
h_all=(1:1:m).';

for i=1:m
    for j=1:m
        LHS=lhs4+lhs1(i,:)+lhs2(j,:); %mx(n-1)
        for k=1:m
            h=h_all.*(sum(LHS>rhs3(k,:),2)<Q); %mx1
            h(h==0)=[]; %delete the zeros
            %HOW DO I STORE {i,j,k,h}?
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `quantile(A_1(i,2:end)+A_2(j,2:end)+A_3(k,2:end)+A_4(h,2:end), 0.95)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for this.

Comment: Note that if like the linked question the value of `m` is `10^5` and %95 of the data matches the condition and you want to store indices of the cases that don't match (i.e. the remaining %5) as int32 you need near 17.3 [exabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte) of memory. And 10^20 exceeds uint64 index range.

Comment: I know, that m is too large. I definitively need to work with smaller array but I still need an efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

Like the linked answer you can at each step precompute the matrices. Result is a logical `m^4` matrix than can be converted to subscripts:

```
lhs4=A_4(:,1)-A_4(:,2:end); 
lhs1=A_1(:,1)-A_1(:,2:end);
lhs2=A_2(:,1)-A_2(:,2:end);
rhs3=A_3(:,2:end)-A_3(:,1);
Q = .95 * (n - 1);

check = false (m,m,m,m); 

for i=1:m
    lhsi = lhs4 + lhs1(i,:);
    for j=1:m
        lhsj = lhsi + lhs2(j,:);
        for k=1:m    
            rhsk = rhs3(k,:);
            check(:,k,j,i) = sum (lhsj > rhsk , 2) < Q;
        end             
    end
end
f = find (check);
[H,K,J,I] = ind2sub ([m m m m], f) ;
```